# How to separate two columns with the same name while using JOIN LEFT?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

MySQL table looks like this:

```
markers
id, tid,        lat,    lng
1   1           42.000  2.500
2   1           41.000  2.400
3   2           40.000  2.300

markers_types
id, name,   image
1   TYPE1   type1.png
2   TYPE2   type2.png
```

While using CodeIgniter's Active Records:

```
function get_coordinates(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('markers');
    $this->db->join('markers_types', 'markers.tid = markers_types.id');
    $this->db->where('state', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if( $query->result() < 1 ) return FALSE;

    $results = $query->result();
    return $results;

}
```

It concatenate (or merge) two columns named `id` into the one, from two different tables. How to prevent that? And is it possible to prevent from merging these columns without renaming them ?

Comment: modify your `$this->db->select('*');` statement to list out the individual **table.field** names you want to capture in your response.

Comment: the 'merging' you refer to actually is the criterion by which to associate records from the different tables over which the join is defined. if that is not what you want, you can specify a cross join giving you the cartesian product of both tables. i cannot help you with the code igniter syntax to specify that.

Comment: Be like 10% less lazy and `SELECT markers.*, markers_types.name, markers_types.image` or 90% less lazy and actually specify only the fields you're interested in, or 100% less lazy and give the columns alias names that are actually descriptive, aka `SELECT markers_types.name AS 'marker_type_name'`. Let this be a lesson to you to not use "id" as a column name more than once, or ever.

Comment: I tried `$this->db->select('markers.*')`, it worked, until I got an error while doing an `foreach($items as $i){$i->image}` telling me that: `Undefined property: stdClass::$image` any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your `$this->db->select('*');` statement to list out the individual *table.field* names you want to capture in your response.

```
$this->db->select('markers.type_id, markers.lat, markers.lng, markers_types.id, markers_types.name, markers_types.image');
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i tried this with the one suggested by **@Sammitch**, `$this->db->select('markers.*, markers_types.name, markers_types.image');` and it worked also!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to DevlshOne's answer i would use explicit select values, but to differentiate you can alias your select values as well, something like this:

```
$this->db->select('markers.type_id as m_id, markers.lat, markers.lng, markers_types.id as mt_id, markers_types.name, markers_types.image');
```